# How to get IEEE conference template to show conference name in header?

Tags: header-footer, ieeetran

I want to get the title of a conference to appear as shown in the figure which (for `IEEEtran` class) might be done using `\markboth{\textbf{\textit{2020 IEEE PES/IAS PowerAfrica}}}{}`. However, when passing the option `conference`, the headers entirely disappear

[image]

One requirement for the solution is to remove page numbering.

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\begin{document}
    
    % ===== The Paper Title =====
    \title{Statistical Analysis of Wind Power Using Weibull Distribution to Maximize Energy Yield}
    
    % ===== Author names =====
    \author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh}
        \IEEEauthorblockA{
            \textit{Tafila Technical University}
            \\
            \textit{Electrical Power and Mechatronics Engineering Department}
            \\
            Tafila, Jordan
            \\
            almotasem.aldaoudeye@ndsu.edu
            }
        \and
        \IEEEauthorblockN{Khaled Alzaareer}
        \IEEEauthorblockA{
            \textit{Electrical Engineering Department}
            \\
            \textit{Quebec University (ETS) }
            \\
            Montreal, Canada 
            \\
            kaledz87@yahoo.com
            }
        }
    
    % ===== Conference Name =====
    \markboth{\textbf{\textit{2020 IEEE PES/IAS PowerAfrica}}}{}

    % ===== Title =====
    \maketitle
    
    % ===== The Abstract =====
    \begin{abstract}
    
        \blindtext
    
    \end{abstract}
    
    % ===== Keywords =====
    \begin{IEEEkeywords}
        
        power-speed characteristics, capacity factor, wind energy yield
        
    \end{IEEEkeywords}
    
    
    % ===== Copyright =====
    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
    \IEEEpubid{%
        \adjustbox{raise=-2.5\baselineskip}{\makebox[\columnwidth]{\space\textbf{978-1-7281-6746-6/20/\$31.00~\copyright2020 IEEE} \hfill} \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{~}}
        }
    
    \blinddocument
    
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In conference mode, some of the commands are intentionally disabled and `\markboth{}{}` is one of those. So, using `\IEEEoverridecommandlockouts` should have worked for it but unfortunately, it doesn't (I don't know the reason).

Now, I have found a solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375510/219947). As I have seen people advise to add the full solution along with the link, I am also adding the solution here.

In the preamble, you can add the following code snippet to show the conference name.

```
\usepackage[mathlines,switch]{lineno}

\makeatletter

\let\old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle
\def\confheader#1{%
    % for the first page
    \def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
        \old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle%
        \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
        \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
    }%
    \ps@headings%
}
\makeatother

\confheader{%
        \parbox{20cm}{\textbf{\textit{2020 IEEE PES/IAS PowerAfrica}}}
}
```

Here is an MWE based on the question:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}

\usepackage[mathlines,switch]{lineno}

\makeatletter

\let\old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle
\def\confheader#1{%
    % for the first page
    \def\ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle{%
        \old@ps@IEEEtitlepagestyle%
        \def\@oddhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
        \def\@evenhead{\strut\hfill#1\hfill\strut}%
    }%
    \ps@headings%
}
\makeatother

\confheader{%
    \parbox{20cm}{\textbf{\textit{2020 IEEE PES/IAS PowerAfrica}}}
}
\begin{document}
    
    % ===== The Paper Title =====
    \title{Statistical Analysis of Wind Power Using Weibull Distribution to Maximize Energy Yield}
    
    % ===== Author names =====
    \author{\IEEEauthorblockN{Al-Motasem I. Aldaoudeyeh}
        \IEEEauthorblockA{
            \textit{Tafila Technical University}
            \\
            \textit{Electrical Power and Mechatronics Engineering Department}
            \\
            Tafila, Jordan
            \\
            almotasem.aldaoudeye@ndsu.edu
        }
        \and
        \IEEEauthorblockN{Khaled Alzaareer}
        \IEEEauthorblockA{
            \textit{Electrical Engineering Department}
            \\
            \textit{Quebec University (ETS) }
            \\
            Montreal, Canada 
            \\
            kaledz87@yahoo.com
        }
    }
    
    % ===== Conference Name =====
    \markboth{\textbf{\textit{2020 IEEE PES/IAS PowerAfrica}}}{}
    
    % ===== Title =====
    \maketitle
    
    % ===== The Abstract =====
    \begin{abstract}
        
        \blindtext
        
    \end{abstract}
    
    % ===== Keywords =====
    \begin{IEEEkeywords}
        
        power-speed characteristics, capacity factor, wind energy yield
        
    \end{IEEEkeywords}
    
    
    % ===== Copyright =====
    \IEEEoverridecommandlockouts
    \IEEEpubid{%
        \adjustbox{raise=-2.5\baselineskip}{\makebox[\columnwidth]{\space\textbf{978-1-7281-6746-6/20/\$31.00~\copyright2020 IEEE} \hfill} \hspace{\columnsep}\makebox[\columnwidth]{~}}
    }
    
    \blinddocument
    
\end{document}
```

Screenshot of a portion of the output pdf
[image: OutputImage]

Please note that one may need to install the 'TeX Gyre Termes' font to successfully run this code.